# How to get notification badge in actionbar item using Titanium

Tags: notifications, android-actionbar, titanium, badge

I am developing application using Titanium and want feature to have a badge of notification in the action bar in Android as shown in attached image.

[image]

From Android native we can achieve the same using actionLayout property from the menu >> item tag.

But not clear how can we do the same using Titanium.

At least I need suggestion or guidance from where I can move ahead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Android Notification](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Android_Notifications) tutorial from Titanium documentation.

There should be all you need.  However, I'm not sure what do you mean by badge. There is [appBadge property](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iPhone-property-appBadge) but it works only for iOS system.